# Overlaying a transparent PNG on top of the current location blue dot

Tags: ios

i'm just playing around with Apple's CurrentAddress sample code and I was trying to use the trueHeading property to determine the direction the user is facing. While that proved simple enough, I wanted to display a transparent PNG on top of the current location dot and I wanted to rotate it in order to simulate a compass.

Here's the very basic code I've currently got:

```
@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView, reverseGeocoder, getAddressButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}



- (IBAction)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation
{
    self.reverseGeocoder =
        [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate] autorelease];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot obtain address."
                                                        message:errorMessage
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    PlacemarkViewController *placemarkViewController =
        [[PlacemarkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlacemarkViewController" bundle:nil];
    placemarkViewController.placemark = placemark;
    [self presentModalViewController:placemarkViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    // we have received our current location, so enable the "Get Current Address" button
    [getAddressButton setEnabled:YES];
    NSString *north = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.mapView.userLocation.heading.trueHeading];
    NSLog(@"here: %@", north);
}

@end
```

How can I overlay the PNG to the exact position of the blue dot and keep it there (following the dot if the user moves, that is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you need to implement `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method and look inside it for annotation objects which are not yours. Take a look at the code snipped:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSString static *defaultID = @"defaultID";
    NSString static *userLocationID = @"userLocationID";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {
        // your code here
    } else {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:userLocationID];
        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:userLocationID] autorelease];
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UserLocationIcon.png"];
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer, some urgent matters came up. OK, seems simple enough, i'll try to add the overlay in the "your code here" part.

Comment: No, "your code here" are the place for annotations you add by yourself (of course in case you add any), you need to implement the other part. You see, there is a "UserLocationIcon.png", which will be shown instead of default blue user pin.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm also getting a shadowed declaration error regarding *annotationView. Any ideas?

Comment: It was a redeclaration of `annotationView` in the internal `if`. It should be fine right now.

Comment: Works perfect, apart from the fact that it obliterates the blue dot as well as the gps blue radius. I was hoping I could overlay another png on top of that dot.